# How to display bitmap from internal storage?

Tags: android, bitmap, loading

I  saved my bitmap images in my  internal storage but  i  can't  redisplay it. I've been researching for a long time but i've not find yet.

```
public static void saveImages(Activity activity) throws IOException
    {  
        for (int i=0; i<categories.getItems().length; i++) {        
            OutputStream os2 = activity.openFileOutput(categories.getItems()[i].getName(),
                    Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw2 = new OutputStreamWriter(os2);
            Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)categories.getItems()[i].getCategoryImage()).getBitmap(); 
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, os2);
            osw2.close();
        }
    }
```

This  code works succesfully to  save  images. I will  redisplay  that  images  from  files.
Thank you

Comment: Sorr i  couldn't  format my code. I am newbie for this site.

Comment: Just select all your code and press Ctrl+Shift+K . That should work.I can't edit your question or I would do that instead of you.

Comment: @sharp http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/2/

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
    File f=new File(yourdir, imagename);
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code: uses `openFileInput` to fetch the streams you saved and then decodes them:

```
for (int i=0; i<categories.getItems().length; i++) {        
InputStream is = activity.openFileInput(categories.getItems()[i].getName());
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

// do whatever you need with b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

decode bitmap, and then make a new imageView then add the bitmap to the imageView.

Comment: For decoding i have  to know  folders  path, but i don't  know.

Comment: Try Log.d("", "storage location" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());and watch your log in the DDMS