# Android - get Saved Bitmap from internal Storage and with ID

Tags: android, bitmap

How can I get a saved Bitmap from internal Storage with the Resource ID?

```
saveImageToInternalStorage(context, bitmap, "car" );
int drawable = getImageFromInternalStorage(context, "car"); // <- How to do this and put it in the Array imageIDs below?

final int[] imageIDs = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
                R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f , drawable };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to display bitmap from internal storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593737/how-to-display-bitmap-from-internal-storage...this) might help...u need to create file input/outputstream and specify path in order to get the bitmapimage...